# How would Blockly entries be scored?

Tags: discussion

If there was a [Blockly](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/apps/index.html) entry how would the source be included (by screenshot?) and how would the source length be counted (for [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf))?

[image]

Comment: Looks like those languages basically have the same concept. In principle I'd score by "atoms", but see the answers on the previous question.

Comment: Actually scratch the bit about atoms. That's how I would score a Blockly-only challenge. A Blockly entry to a code golf... I don't know. I guess figuring out the information content would be fairest. Alternatively, I'm sure that you can save that source code in a file... how big is that file? ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't know about Blockly, but taking the size of the binary file of a Scratch program would be inaccurate: Scratch saves the values of variables between runs, presumably increasing the byte count.

Comment: @BetaDecay I said source file not binary file, but since I don't know the language, these concepts might not make sense.

Comment: Another possible measure: what's the smallest number of ASCII characters you need to communicate to someone unambiguously how to enter the program. I suppose if you just wrote down all the characters you can see in the graphical representation, plus statement/block separators, that would also make sense.

Comment: [Here](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/apps/code/index.html) it seems to allow you to export the program in a different language, so you could choose the shortest program out of the various languages and use it...

Comment: Why do we need a count for Blocky that's comparable to text-based languages? It's apples and oranges. Either Blocky will get unfair advantage or have no chance of getting the accept. Realistically, answers only compete with others of the same language, so any metric that's reasonable and consistent for Blocky (and maybe Scratch) would be fine.

Comment: @xnor Good point, but that would *still* mean that Blockly can never make an accepted answer, because it's not comparable to other answers.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I understand, but I think this is already effectively true for verbose text-based languages like Java, yet people contribute Java answers. Being accepted isn't that big a deal.